# How to edit XPS files?

Tags: pdf, xps-file

XPS files are Microsoft's rival to Adobe's PDF format.

How to edit or create new XPS files in Ubuntu?!

Answer (score 5):

Master PDF Editor provides you advanced functions for working with PDF and XPS formats:

- Create new PDF and XPS files or edit existing ones.
- Add and/or edit bookmarks in PDF files.
- Encrypt and/or protect PDF files using 128 bit encryption.
- Convert XPS files into PDF.
- Add PDF controls (like buttons, checkboxes, lists, etc.) into your
  PDFs.
- Import/export PDF pages into common graphical formats including
  BMP, JPG, PNG, and TIFF.
- Free PDF Editor on Linux ( for non-commercial use)

Ubuntu users can install Master PDF Editor by using Ubuntu Software Center(Old versions)

```
sudo apt-get install master-pdf-editor
```

[Official source](http://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor.php)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution that I'm aware of isn't great... Through Google Drive (Docs).

http://googledocs.blogspot.be/2011/02/12-new-file-formats-in-google-docs.html

Answer (score 1):

This is how I modify an XPS file :

1. open the XPS using the document viewer.
2. print the XPS in a file and choose SVG format.
3. open it with Inkscape (https://inkscape.org/en/).

You can then modify it, render a high-resolution PNG, etc.

To create one, I would print in a file and choose PostScript format, I think this is the closest to XPS.

Answer (score 1):

**Converting from XPS**

The package `libgxps-utils` includes tools that can be used to convert XPS files to JPG, PNG, PDF, PS, and SVG.

**Editing**

At this point, users may use any method they are aware of to edit the converted files.

**Converting (via PS) to XPS**

There is an output driver `xpswrite` that comes with Ghostscript.  In principle, it should be able to convert from any format `gs` can read, but the fonts of files I tested tended to become unreadable.

To get fonts to render properly in XPS, files need to first be converted to PS, independently of `gs`.  For instance, PDF files can be converted to PS with `pdftops`.  However, `pdf2ps` will *not* work because it is simply a script that calls `gs`.

```
pdftops input.pdf    # convert to ps first
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=xpswrite -sOutputFile=output.xps input.ps
```

**Viewing**

Common PS/PDF viewers, such as Evince and Okular, can render XPS files for viewing.